# Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm thinking of asking a question about [AngularJS 2.0 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) and it made me wonder if there should be an [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) tag separate from the current [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag.

Having seen AngularJS 2.0 code and markup and listened to some of the core AngularJS team talk about it, I'm convinced it is quite a different beast to AngularJS 1.x to merit a separate tag.

As a practitioner of AngularJS 1.x and an answerer of questions on SE with the [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag I can see that it could be confusing in the future to see an [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tagged question that relates to AngularJS 2.0.

If the consensus is that there should be a separate tag what would be the ideal name? [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) may be too specific to a version number. Maybe [angularjs-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.x), but that doesn't feel right. I guess this could be another question in itself.

Comment: You probably need to add a motivation why this might be necessary. You should start a discussion with your own arguments.

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge of Angular 1.x and Angular 2, yes. Absolutely yes.

Comment: It's so radically different than angular 1.x, there's no question it should be a separate tag.

Comment: Definetely. It will be a completely different thing, the core team has made that crystal clear.

Comment: Actually, you also want an angularjs-1 tag. And all the old questions tagged with that.

Comment: @Deduplicator My slight concern with having angularjs-1, angularjs-2, etc. is what happens when AngularJS 3.0 arrives and it isn't as radical a change but more like a natural progession?

Comment: I think you should talk with the python community how they do that, as they radically changed their string types and general text handling. I think there's no neat answer for that though...

Comment: I completely agree. To avoid missing questions you might be able to answer, the tag filtering system should perhaps include angularjs-1, angularjs-2 and angularjs-3 when browsing for simply angularjs? But specifying the version would absolutely improve the angularjs help, in my opinion.

Comment: AngularJS 2.0 will not be a "completely different thing". Stop thinking that. It will even almost be backward compatible. We will need an `angularjs-2.x` tag, for sure, but please don't re-tag everything with an over-specific `angularjs-1.x`.

Comment: I agree that we should have a separate tag for each version of Angular.  
angularjs, angularjs-1, angularjs-2, angular-dart, angular-dart-1,   
angular-dart-2

Comment: I think a good idea @Deduplicator might be to rename the angularjs tag to angularjs-1.0, mark it for questions using the OLD version, and then add a new tag for angularjs/angularjs-2.0

Comment: I suggested edit of `angularjs` tag to mention it's also known as *AngularJS 1* so that people who read the tag description before using it will not use it for *Angular 2* questions - http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14348333

Answer (score 18):

**Yes.** I feel Angular-2.0 is VERY different from Angular-1.0 to the point that someone who has been working on Angular-1.0 for a long time won't necessarily be able to answer questions for someone who is working with Angular-2.0.

I think the main thing we should ask is **can someone who knows Angular-1.0 help someone who is working on an Angular-2.0 project?** If the answer is no, I do not see a reason why these two should not be separated.

Because this piqued my interest, I decided to do some research on what tags have versioning and what don't. I focused primarily on frameworks.

I ran a query to see what tags has the word `2.0` in the tag name [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=2.0&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). The ones I feel are similar to being considered a "framework" would include

**Frameworks with versions**

[cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp), [cakephp-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.3), [cakephp-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.0), [cakephp-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.0)

[knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js), [knockout-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout-2.0)

[durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/durandal), [durandal-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/durandal-2.0)

[playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework), [playframework-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0)

However, there do seem to be many that do not have versioning for tags

**Frameworks without**

[django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) (v1.8)

[emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emberjs) (v1.11.1)

[marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marionette) (v2.4.1) (based on [backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone) (v1.1.2))

[react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) (v0.11.2)

[express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) (v4) ([express4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express4) exists but very few questions)

[meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) (v1.1.0.2)

[polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) (v0.5.5)

[yui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yui) (v3.18.1)

[passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) (based on [locomotivejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locomotivejs) v0.4)

Infer what you want from this.

Comment: You should have also included the number of followers for each. As soon as tags break off into versions the followers of the original tag are slower to adopt following the new tag. So if someone was to post only using `angular-2` their exposure to potential answerers drops dramatically

Comment: @charlietfl that's a really good point. if I have time, I'll try to add that information in.

Comment: To evaluate the effectiveness of version-splitting, you'd also want to consider the impact on answering. Is there any variation in % questions unanswered? Time to answer? Upvotes received on answers?

Answer (score 5):

[Angular v2](https://angular.io/) isn't even called AngularJS anymore. It's plain **ANGULAR**. It's more generic and supports other languages other than Javascript(ECx). It supports [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) as well.

Delving down to the framework itself, Angular(v2) and AngularJS(v1) seem different in the internals as well. For example, Angular doesn't use `scope` anymore, where as in AngularJS, [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) is super dominant.

So the answer is YES! There should be a separate tag.

I would even suggest separating Angular from AngularJS. Currently, they are synonyms.

Comment: True. AngularJS and Angular2 are the real names used by owners.