# What should be the names of the AngularJS tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The responses to this question [Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag) overwhelmingly agree that AngularJS 2.0 should have a separate tag. The question now is what should be the names of the tags for AngularJS 1.x questions and AngularJS 2.0 questions?

Here are some suggestions:

- [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2)
- [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)
- [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), [angularjs-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.x)
- [angularjs-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1), [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2)
- [angularjs-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1), [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)
- [angularjs-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1), [angularjs-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.x)

@aug's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291413/782358) provides some valuable reference for framework tag naming.

My personal preference is [angularjs-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1), [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) as I suspect in the very near future most people will refer to "AngularJS 1" or "AngularJS 2". Keeping the current [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag will become confusing as one would not know which version it refers to.

The reason I have made this a separate question is so that we can vote on the best suggestion.

Comment: This requires the same time-machine that was missing when everybody used [angularjs].  Is, say, version 2.5 going to be very different and require a new tag again?  Just look how other tags do this.  Python 3.0 was a big change, C# 3.0 was very different, C++11 was a very major language revision.  But everybody simply uses [python] and [c#] and [c++] to ask questions.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point but I see that there are the following tags for Python: [python],  [python-2.7],  [python-3.x]. Are you saying everybody just uses [python]?

Comment: Yes, 21 times as many [python] questions, 17 times as many [c++] questions, etc is a pretty decent approximation for "everybody".  Also note how for example 67% of the [python-2.7] questions also have the [python] tag :)

Comment: You might want to look up the meaning of "overwhelming"... 7 users said "yes", but nobody provided a convincing reason for doing so. Aug's answer focused on the argument "but all the other kids are doing it", ignoring the negative impact that version-splitting has had on those tags

Comment: @Mogsdad I know what overwhelming means. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3):

## I vote for: [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [angular-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2.0).

**Why we need to keep** [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)**?**

- Many AngularJS 1 concepts will still apply in Angular 2, so we need a generic tag.
- An expert in AngularJS 1 will likely be able to answer some questions of Angular 2 and likely be interested in the framework evolution. So, mistagged questions will not be a big problem.

**Why we need a** [angular-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2.0)**?**

- I'm an AngularJS user and I agree with [meta people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag) that version 2 requires a new tag due to the huge difference.
- A future expert in Angular 2 that do not know AngularJS 1 will likely not be interested in learning the previous framework to answer more questions. So, his favorite tag could be only [angular-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2.0)

**Why** [angular-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2.0) **and not a** [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) **or** [angularjs-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.x)**?**

- The [official site](https://angular.io/) calls it Angular 2.0. They've even dropped the JS in the name.
- [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) and others can be a synonym.
- When Angular 2.1 is launched, the difference will be small and calling it Angular 2.0 will not be a problem. However, we may require an [angular-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-3.0) in the future.

**Why not a** [angularjs-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.0)**?**

- Retagging old questions will be a waste of time.
- Concepts and some code will be the same in AngularJS 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Btw, while renaming `angularjs` to `angularjs-1.0` wouldn't be a hassle (can be done quickly by mods or via synonyms), it's just unnecessary.

Comment: I agree that [angular-2.0] is better than [angularjs-2.0]. I'm not sure I agree with your points to keep [angularjs]. The concepts appear to be very different and an expert in **just** 1.x would have a hard time answering 2.x questions IMHO.

Comment: @camden_kid there's more to it than just the the framework, there's the use of SO itself and favorited tags also to consider. How quickly do 15K followers switch? Right now there are already duplicate `angular 2x` tags and anyone tagging a question with only those tags will get more limited exposure  to potential answerers

Answer (score 0):

I prefer angularjs-1.X and angularjs. Why? Because most people will be still using plain [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) to ask questions about angularjs 2. Newer questions all of them (specially so, since there will be several "Y U no work now", from people trying to use angular 1.x guidance in the newer version) will be a huge avalance and retagging all of them as [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) isn't worth the effort.

So, angularjs-1.x for newer questions that are specific to that series of angular and angularjs for everything else.

Essentially what it's proposed in [MSE about version specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147085/213575).