# Merge [angular2] and [angularjs-2.0] and [angularjs-2]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Since the angular framework has a good sized following and version 2 is very different than 1.x series might be a good time to merge [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) and [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0).

These tags have limited and about equal followers and questions but I'm sure that will grow quickly

Comment: Which is why I preferred that only new questions would get -1.x tag. It gets silly very quickly (and most of the time, people only use them to say that they are using X version, instead of a direct relation to the version of angular used, [like it should be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/213575)). BTW, some even have the 3 tags [angularjs], [angular2] and [angular-2.0]. Counter proposal, merge them all into angularjs, and only tag new questions that are irrevocably related to the first version use [angularjs-1.x].

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291426/what-should-be-the-names-of-the-angularjs-tags

Comment: @Braiam totally agree since adoption rate of followers to answer new version tags is much lower than potential questions that might only get tagged with the new version

Comment: I agree, I've found [a question with 3 AngularJS 2.0 tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34434521/1064325)! So, in addition to [tag:angular2], there is also [tag:anguarjs-2], which should both be retagged/synonymized to [tag:angularjs-2.0], the main tag.

Comment: No news about this? i was about to create a request so these 3 tags are merged. I totally vote for having only `angular2`.

Answer (score 8):

My vote is that we merge the [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) and [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) tags into the [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) tag. If you look at the [Angular2.0 site](https://angular.io/), the new version isn't even called AngularJS anymore, it's just Angular. That makes the tags [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) and [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) not only confusing but almost downright wrong.

This would keep people from having to tag their question not one, not two, but [**THREE TIMES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668826/angular-2-cant-access-response-headers-in-a-http-request).

Comment: +1 for using the correct term "downright" because I get angry by people saying "damn right".

Comment: When will the merge happen? The `angularjs-2.0` tag still exists.