# Merge [angularjs-(.+)] --> [angular-$1]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

(UPDATE: I've reversed the order of which direction the tag merges should go.)

[angularjs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive) -> [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive)

[angularjs-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ngmodel) -> [angular-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-model)

[angularjs-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap) -> [angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap)

[angularjs-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller) -> [angular-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-controller)

[angularjs-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filters) -> [angular-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters)

etc. In general, `angularjs-(.+)` --> `angular-$1`.

Comment: I think that all the angular-* tags should remain angular-* with no js with the exception of the main tag angularjs. Typing the extra js is a little annoying and no one says angularjs colloquially

Comment: 'angularjs' is historical and official name of Angular 1.x. The things that shouldn't exist are 'angularjs-2*'

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: Sure, as long as they're all the same and we don't have both `angularjs-foo` and `angular-foo` tags

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: I've updated the merges to go in the other direction as per popular demand

Comment: Frankly even with the reverse direction... I just don't see this as a real issue. No one is really getting confused with it or anything.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: It just splinters the tag unnecessarily. If I have a question about directives, do I use `angular-directive` or `angularjs-directive`? They both have lots of questions there. There's just no reason at all to have two of them - they should be tag synonyms. That being said people probably don't usually filter on a particular tag like that so in the grand scheme it probably doesn't matter too much. Just the overarching desire for tidiness =P.

Comment: related: [Asking an \[angular-ng-*\] question is as easy as picking from four different tag formats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283216/1048572), [What should be the names of the AngularJS tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291426/1048572) and [Burninate 73 AngularJS directive tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296857/1048572)