# Synonymize [angular-1.x] with [angularjs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

This topic has been discussed before in [Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291347/215552), and [What should be the names of the AngularJS tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291426/215552). However, the "creativity" of users with 1500+ rep knows no bounds, and we now have [angular-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-1.x). I've removed it if it already had [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) or used the more apt [angularjs-1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.5) where appropriate, but I can't suggest a synonym due to the restriction of version-specific tag synonyms to mods.

Comment: Marked this [meta-tag:status-completed], as [tag:angular-1.x] no longer exists.