# Synonymize Angular1.x tag

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Can we get the [angular1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x) synonymized into the [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) one? It seems to have originated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802180/passing-scope-to-services-seems-like-a-good-idea-but) and has been used a [few dozen times since](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x).

This has been requested a [few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346079/angular1-x-is-a-synonym-of-angularjs) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339711/synonymize-angular-1-x-with-angularjs) already but with the work that is being put in to [clean up all of the Angular tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2) it seems important to bring this back up again.

Along with that, I also don't believe that burninating it is the right answer either, as one commenter mentioned, because I think that making a tag as confusing as [angular1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x) (since v1 was never known as Angular but v2+ is) a synonym would be better than outright burninating it.