# Should changing Angular to AngularJS be accepted?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I search and see the related question [Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag) and [Should we remove the angularjs tag from angular2 questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315474/should-we-remove-the-angularjs-tag-from-angular2-questions), but still have  doubts.

When reviewing suggested edits, I see [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17077576) just changing "Angular" to "AngularJS", with comments

> Changed Angular to AngularJS - this allows search engines to use "angular NOT angularjs" syntax

I click the reject button and find there is someone casting **no improvement whatsoever**. So what is better , Reject or Approve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code base being referenced is over five years old - and as we discussed in that rename topic, there's enough differences between Angular and AngularJS that they should be cordoned into their own tags.

It'd be better if the edit also incorporated the code from the broken links into the post, though.  At a minimum, they only changed one label and that's not quite sufficient enough IMO for improvement.

I'd personally go "Reject and Edit" and add in the missing source, but it's a judgment call at this point.  Five years is prehistoric enough in AngularJS that I doubt anyone's going to get much value out of that question or answer anyway.

Comment: The primary issue isn't whether or not it helps people with AngularJS / 1.x questions, those of us who are searching for Angular 2+ questions have to do a lot of manual filtering of questions from the old codebase as they contain the term "Angular".  Also, what do you mean by "incorporated the code from the broken links"?